# Problem with writing matrix equation

Tags: tables, equations, matrices

How to write an equation involving matrices in latex?

Say a 2x2 matix multiplied by a 2x1 matrix equals to a 2x1 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}&\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1\\\eta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m\\n\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
```